# Обнуления счетчика при добавлении новой записи в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Есть две таблицы. В одной автоинкремент id файла , в другом автоинкремент id страницы. Таблицы связаны ключом по id файла. В итоге хочу сделать так,чтобы при изменении id файла, id страницы обнулялся. Для простоты и понятности прикреплю пример [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите,возможно ли как то это реализовать ?
[Схема Базы Данных](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i6bu.jpg)

Comment: А это какая из двух таблиц приведена в виде картинки ? какой в этой таблице первичный ключ ?

Comment: @Mike вставил схему в вопрос

Comment: Т.е. на картинке в самом вопросе у вас именно вторая таблица. А первичный ключ в ней все еще idPage. Но первичный ключ в таблице обязан быть уникальным. Если idPage начнется опять с 1, то он уже не будет уникален, следовательно это поле уже не сможет быть первичным ключом (так же как и автоинкрементом, который придуман собственно для гарантии этой самой уникальности)

Comment: @Mike что в данном случае делать первичным ключом в таблице Page тогда?Есть ли смысль добавить уникальный ID?И что тогда с автоинкрементом IdPage делать?

Comment: @richardgir всё у вас в порядке с первичными ключами, добавьте внешние ключи и будет вам счастье.

Comment: ну idPage по логике - это правильный первичный ключ, потому что он уникально идентифицирует конкретную страницу. Вдруг вы на эту таблицу захотите из третьей таблицы сослаться, вы же будете это по первичному ключу делать. А вот если вы хотите порядковую нумерацию страниц внутри одного файла, то ее вообще хранить не надо, так как всегда можно получить когда она понадобится.

Comment: Ну в очень редких случаях конечно можно захотеть что бы на страницу можно было ссылаться только с указанием и файла и страницы, тогда и первичным ключом будет связка idFile-IdPage (только idPage тогда стоит переименовать ибо он уже не отражает собой именно id страницы). Но тогда никакого автоинкремента, придется делать свой велосипедно-костыльный генератор последовательных номеров

Comment: @Mike то есть хранить не надо порядковую нумерацию? мне нужно понимать просто при вызове определенной страницы какой ее номер и из какого она файла взята.

Comment: А как именно будет происходить этот вызов ? какие параметры вы при этом будете получать от клиента для понимания какую страницу он хочет ? И кстати, откуда вообще появляются эти страницы, они вводятся хаотически или например вы берете тот самый файл, читаете его и разбиваете на страницы, т.е. одномоментно создаете все записи относящиеся к данному файлу ?

Comment: @Mike скорее второе. Разбиваю страницы на текст. Осуществляю поиск по тексту , и мне выводит вхождение,где должно быть написано с какой  страницы текста и какого файла найдено вхождение

Comment: Тогда вам видимо особо не нужен idPage. Я бы сделал вместо него поле с номером страницы (pageNum) и первичный ключ был бы `primary key(idFile, pageNum)`.  И никакого автоинкремента бы конечно не делал, а нумеровал страницы на стороне клиента, при вставке. ему виднее с каким номером они должны быть, потому как в документах нумерация по разным причинам может быть не с 1. И когда вы файл целиком грузите в БД писать в поле числа подряд 1,2,3 труда не составит.

Comment: Единственное неудобство, если вы захотите сохранить где то список того, что вы нашли, то там на страницы надо будет ссылаться сразу двумя полями idFile и pageNum, что в принципе логично, можно из этого потом легко получить список файлов, где есть вхождения и прямо выводить "найдено в файле таком то на страницах 1,7,9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя внешние ключи?
В момент создания таблицы вы определяете какая из таблиц на какую ссылается и делаете в ней внешний ключ

```
FOREIGN KEY (IdFile)  REFERENCES Files (Id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Второй вариант используя триггеры.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_DELETE_FILE BEFORE DELETE ON [Files] FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  // Тут делаете что хотите при удалении
END
```

Comment: не совсем вас понял. вот схематично изобразил БД [ссылка](https://imgur.com/a/Iur68xU)

Comment: Что именно непонятно? механизм БД уже предусматривает то что вы хотите, называется это "внешние ключи" когда поле одной таблицы имеет связь с полем(полями) в другой таблице. при изменении записей, а именно этого поля, возможны несколько вариантов автоматических действий со всеми записями которые ссылаются на это поле.(незнаю, но помоему так еще менее понятно стало)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внешний_ключ

Comment: почему у вас удаление ? У меня задача при добавлении нового файла.

Comment: Потому что это пример, замените ON DELETE на ON INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Можешь сам проставить нужные Id

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Page ON

INSERT Page (IdPage, IdFile) VALUES (1, 1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Page OFF
```

Comment: ТС хочет что бы у него первичный ключ был не уникальным, так что это все бесполезно, ему надо переосмыслить задачу

Comment: Это тут причем вообще?

Comment: Я прочитал заголовок вопроса. "Обнуления счетчика при добавлении новой записи в MS SQL". Но потом уже прочитал суть проблемы. Там неправильный подход.